# Why is the column taking full width of it's parent (Container)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

1. I have a column inside a container
2. The width of the container is set to 300
3. The column has a text child
4. Now generally, the column width will be the width of it's widest child. In this case, it has just one text child and so the width of column should be the width of text child
5. However, the column expands to the full width of the parent being 300 i.e. container parent with width of 300

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            child: Column(
              // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text('Hi', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

6. We can observe the fact that the column is expanding to full width of it's parent by seeing in the image that the child is center aligned which is the default cross axis alignment.

[image]

I went through the container docs but could not figure out why it is happening. Can someone please explain as to why the column is taking full width of it's parent?

Comment: Try to give width by MediaQuery class then see what's happening

Comment: reasoning given by both Alex Radzishevsky and Guillaume Roux are both satisfactory and I just happen to choose one for the reference to the actual code and to close the question. But that apart both the answers are equally important. Thank You!

Comment: Hi  Prabhanshu Tiwari, if I use 'MediaQuery.of(context).size.width', the column again expands to the full width which is an expected behavior in the current context. However, the doubt is why it is expanding to the full width and the reason is mentioned clearly in the 2 answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand how `Container` works here is the implementation for the widget which you can find in the flutter sources:

```dart
Container({
  Key? key,
  this.alignment,
  this.padding,
  this.color,
  this.decoration,
  this.foregroundDecoration,
  double? width,
  double? height,
  BoxConstraints? constraints,
  this.margin,
  this.transform,
  this.transformAlignment,
  this.child,
  this.clipBehavior = Clip.none,
}) : assert(margin == null || margin.isNonNegative),
       assert(padding == null || padding.isNonNegative),
       assert(decoration == null || decoration.debugAssertIsValid()),
       assert(constraints == null || constraints.debugAssertIsValid()),
       assert(clipBehavior != null),
       assert(decoration != null || clipBehavior == Clip.none),
       assert(color == null || decoration == null,
         'Cannot provide both a color and a decoration\n'
         'To provide both, use "decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)".',
       ),
       constraints =
        (width != null || height != null)
          ? constraints?.tighten(width: width, height: height)
            ?? BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: width, height: height)
          : constraints,
       super(key: key);
```

The interesting part is with the `constraints` property:

```dart
constraints =
  (width != null || height != null)
    ? constraints?.tighten(width: width, height: height)
      ?? BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: width, height: height)
    : constraints
```

As you can see if you give a value to the `width` and/or `height` properties it will apply a `BoxConstraints` to its children forcing your child widget `Column` to comply to this constraints.

### Update: How the `alignment` property works ?

If you look in the source code for the `Container` widget you will find this in its `build` method.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget? current = child;

  // ...

  if (alignment != null)
    current = Align(alignment: alignment!, child: current);

  // ...
}
```

It means that by providing a non-null `alignment` property your `child` widget will be wrapped inside an `Align` widget. Now let's take a look at the `Align` widget implementation, more precisely at its `createRenderObject()` method:

```dart
@override
RenderPositionedBox createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
  return RenderPositionedBox(
    alignment: alignment,
    widthFactor: widthFactor,
    heightFactor: heightFactor,
    textDirection: Directionality.maybeOf(context),
  );
}
```

So by providing an `Align` widget it will create a `RenderPositionedBox` let's take a look at its implementation too throught the method `performLayout()`:

```dart
@override
void performLayout() {
  final BoxConstraints constraints = this.constraints;
  final bool shrinkWrapWidth = _widthFactor != null || constraints.maxWidth == double.infinity;
  final bool shrinkWrapHeight = _heightFactor != null || constraints.maxHeight == double.infinity;

  if (child != null) {
    child!.layout(constraints.loosen(), parentUsesSize: true);
    size = constraints.constrain(Size(
      shrinkWrapWidth ? child!.size.width * (_widthFactor ?? 1.0) : double.infinity,
      shrinkWrapHeight ? child!.size.height * (_heightFactor ?? 1.0) : double.infinity,
    ));
    alignChild();
  } else {
    size = constraints.constrain(Size(
      shrinkWrapWidth ? 0.0 : double.infinity,
      shrinkWrapHeight ? 0.0 : double.infinity,
    ));
  }
}
```

And there it is you have some `BoxConstraints` applied to your `child` based on the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` of its parent.

Comment: I was exploring this further and found that if we provide no alignment property in the parent widget, most child widgets are forced to be the size of the parent. I guess in my case since I did not mention any alignment for the container, the column is forced to be the width of container.
However, I did not find the code in Container.dart. Would you be able to point it out please.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some explanations on how the widget behave if you provide an alignment to it. Hope it helps you understand.

Answer (score 5):

Column is taking full width of Container because Container forces it to do so. If you specify width of Container then Container will basically use
ConstrainedBox under the hood with tight constraints for its child. In order words **minWidth = 300** in your case.

If you want Column to be as narrow as possible you should wrap it with UnconstrainedBox widget, which will take Container's tight constraints for himself and make Column to have its "natural" size. If you still want column to be as tall as possible, you need to specify **constrainedAxis: Axis.vertical** property of UnconstrainedBox

Comment: Thank you very much for the reasoning.

1. For this point 'If you want Column to be as narrow as possible you should wrap it with UnconstrainedBox widget' - I can just not mention any constraints of width & height for container and it will be as narrow as possible right?

2. 'wrap it with UnconstrainedBox widget' - I did this and the column still takes full 300 width. Not sure why is it that way!!

Comment: 1. yes; 2. column will not be 300 anymore - but it will column will be centered.  (Use Flutter Inspector to prove that). You can use alignment property of UnconstrainedBox to control alignment though.

Comment: 2. Yes the column is centered and you are absolutely right. Thank you for your time. I wish I could accept both as answers!! -:)

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know why is this behavior like this (that container forces column in this case to expand to container's width, where as the default behavior of column is to be as wide as it's widest child)? 
Is there any logic behind it or is it a choice made by the design team?

Comment: Constraints are always enforced by parent component. So in that case Container (parent) enforces its constraint (to be of specific width) to Column (which is child). This is how Flutter works.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `mainAxisSize` as you have there but giving an`alignment` to the parent Container. If the child is smaller than the parent and there is no alignment, the Container doesn't know where to draw the children, so it forces it to take full size:

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text('Hi', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great Answer. This helps a lot and saves my time. Thank you so much